# Getting error when adding constraint

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, uikit, nslayoutconstraint

I'm trying to set a constraint on 2 `views` so that they touch each other like this:

[image]

I tried setting constraints programmatically:

```
[self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"[_firstView][_secondView]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_firstView, _secondView)]];
```

But I get the following warning:

> Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSArray *' to parameter of type 'NSLayoutConstraint'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `addConstraint:` method expect a single constraint, however the `constraintsWithVisualFormat:` returns an `NSArray` of zero or more constraints.

Try adding an s.

```
[self addConstraints:/*your NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat: call */];
```

Apple's naming conventions can usually help you out here.  Notice that `constraintsWithVisualFormat` is plural while `addConstraint:` was singular (and `addConstraints:` is plural).  Use these as your clue in the future.

Comment: Oh! Thanks!! And just to make sure, the constraint I have will do I the image shows? Meaning flush the 2 views top to bottom?